# Why should I buy an Arduino over a Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

This will probably go -4 in seconds, but I'm genuinely curious and googling hasn't resolved anything.

My potential project:

Power on a device from my smartphone.

I know raspberry pi can do this, but as I was reading through Arduino docs it sounds like if you need a very basic command to fire/read then Arduino is your way to go. At this point is there any advantage in choosing an Arduino over a Pi3?

I know I'm ignorant, but I can't figure out why I would choose Arduino ever again.

Comment: Why would you need a powerful device with a full-fledged OS just to turn a device on and off? Except if you wanted to be featured on [@internetofshit](https://twitter.com/internetofshit). This looks like a job for an ESP8266 or on an existing solution based on that, called Sonoff.

Answer (score 3):

**Price**: The cheapest Raspberry Pi is $5 USD but unless you happen to live somewhere that you can pick one up in person you're going to be paying at least that much again for shipping. Add another $1 for an SD card and say $2 extra for a power supply good enough to make it run reliably. You can buy an Arduino Pro Mini clone for about $1.57 with free shipping or a Nano clone for < $3 with free shipping, any power supply will work, no SD card needed. So you're saving at least $10 on each device you make. If you're already familiar with Raspberry Pi the extra expense may be worth it for the time you will save not needing to learn to use the Arduino.

**Bare metal programming**: There is no operating system to deal with on an Arduino. This simplifies things greatly and improves reliability. The lack of an operating system on the Arduino means you can easily get very precise timing when that is important, though likely this is not relevant to your current project.

**Power consumption**: It's possible to run at extremely low power consumption with an Arduino, especially if you make a few easy modifications to the circuit board (removing the power LED and voltage regulator). It is possible to reduce the power consumption of Raspberry Pi but I don't think you will ever get close to what you can do on an Arduino. This will be more of a concern for a battery powered application.

**Size**: This could depend on which accessories you need to attach to either board but lets consider the likely choice of WiFi as your method of communication between your phone and device. In the Arduino world the cheapest and easiest way to accomplish this would be to use a WeMos D1 Mini, which is less than half the size of the Raspberry Pi Zero.